# Disable seeking with Videogular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

How do you disable seeking on videogular to ensure that users cannot skip the video? I am currently using it on Ionic.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this yet, as I am looking out in 2020 

Comment: Nah, I never did.